# Handling Google+ logins in Android

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-play-services

I have implemented a way for the users to sign in to the application with their Google+ account. In the examples on Google Developers webpage, the login process is connected to the Activity lifecycle: the user is logged in when the Activity starts and logged out when the Activity closes.

The application has one Activity where the login and sign out functionalities can be executed. Though, I might need access to the Google+ services in other activities. To achieve this, I'd need to use the connect method on every Activity and the other methods too. I think this is bad, repeating code. How do I implement this in a good way?

The complete sign in system looks this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private boolean intentInProcess = false;
    private int PLUS_SIGN_IN = 63640;
    private boolean signInClicked = false;
    private ConnectionResult connectionResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if(googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void resolveSignInErrors() {
        if(connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                intentInProcess = true;
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, PLUS_SIGN_IN);
            } catch(SendIntentException e) {
                intentInProcess = false;
                googleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == PLUS_SIGN_IN) {
            if(requestCode != RESULT_OK) {
                signInClicked = false;
            }

            intentInProcess = false;

            if(!googleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                googleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if(!intentInProcess) {
            connectionResult = result;

            if(signInClicked) {
                resolveSignInErrors();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        signInClicked = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void signOutPlus() {
        if(googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(googleApiClient);
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void disconnectPlus() {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(googleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status result) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base Activity that implements `Google Play Services` then extend that activity any time you need to use googe play services

ex.

```
public class GoogleActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener
```

then extend that

```
public class MainActivity extends GoogleActivity
```